# como llamo a una funcion cuando termine de cargar un div en js

Tags: javascript, html

```
function p(){
alert("el div cargo");
}


<div id="prueba">carge?</div>
```

¿como llamo a la funcion p() cuando termine de cargar el div?

¿como los relaciono de esa manera?, no se como relacionarlos intente con un

```
document.getElementById("prueba").addEventListener("load",function(){   p(); });
```

Comment: quisiera que se llamar a la funcion p(). solo se cargarse en div.

Comment: Otro detalle: no veo ninguna relación entre el div y la función

Comment: ¿como los relaciono de esa manera?, no se como relacionarlos intente con un `document.getElementById("prueba").addEventListener("load",function(){
 p();
});`

Comment: @BetaM Te ah dado una respuesta es mas recomendable utilizar **DOMContentLoaded** Ya que estas evaluando si el contenido se a cargado mas no la ventana

Answer (score 1):

1.- Tendrias que agregar un evento `load` a tu documento, esto hara que la funcion se ejecute solo cuando los elementos hayan cargado en nuestro sitio ejemplo:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    p();
  });
```

2.- Tu codigo quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
     p();
 });

function p(){
alert("el div cargo");
}
```

3.- Te puede interesar leer mas sobre esto: [evento load en js](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/load)

Answer (score 1):

De la forma en que tratas de hacerlo no es correcto pues:

- Este evento generalmente se evalúa al objeto `window`
- Dentro de los nodos del DOM solamente aquellos que tienen el atributo `src` tales como una `img` y que dicho recurso se ha cargado
- Tu tratas de darle un listener a un `div` el cual no cumple con el punto anterior.

Ahora si solo importa que el `div` esté cargado en el árbol DOM, entonces te puedes auxiliar del evento [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) el cual:

- Se ejecuta cuando el documento HTML ha sido completamente cargado y parseado

Entonces podemos darle un listener en dicho evento a [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document) que:

- Representa a la página web cargada
- Da un punto de acceso al árbol DOM

Quedando así:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

})
```

Del modo anterior estaremos verificando que el documento completo se haya constituido, eso involucra que ya exista el `div` en cuestión.

Pero aclaro que esto que comparto no estará llamando en momento alguno a la función de forma directa por que el div esté cargado, sino que la ejecutará por que el DOM esta cargado (*eso incluye al `div`*).

```html
    <div id="hola">Hola</div>
    
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        function hola () {
          console.log(1);
        }
        hola();
      })
    </script>
```

**Referencia**

- [Eventos](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#events-2)
- [Evento DOMContentLoaded](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-domcontentloaded)